# Does the number of creatures affected by Sculpt Spells increase with upcasting the spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, spellcasting

As a level 2 Evocation Wizard, the School allows you to sculpt spells around allies, up to 1 + the spell's level, allowing them to avoid the effects of the spell. Certain spells, such as *Thunderwave*, allow you to cast them using a higher level spell slot.

My question is: which level do you use when calculating the amount of allies that can dodge your spell? The actual spell level (for Thunderwave, this is 2), or the level of the spell slot you use when casting (which effectively raises the level of the spell)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is the level of the spell slot you use to cast the spell. From the Player's Basic Rules, page 78:

> Casting a Spell at a Higher Level
>
> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, **the spell assumes the higher level for that casting**. For instance, if Umara casts magic missile using one of her 2nd-level slots, that magic missile is 2nd level. Effectively, the spell expands to fill the slot it is put into. Some spells, such as magic missile and cure wounds, have more powerful effects when cast at a higher level, as detailed in a spell’s description.

When you cast magic missile as a 2nd-level spell, you are casting a 2nd-level spell. That casting, as the rules put it, is at the higher level. The level of the spell is the level you cast it at, for all effects that use the level of the spell.

Answer (score 11):

From page 201 of the *PHB*:

> ### Casting a Spell at a Higher Level
>
> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, **the spell assumes the higher level for that casting.**

Since the spell itself takes on the level of the slot you use, you would use the *"spell slot's level"* to determine the amount of targets you can protect.